# RMI(java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect)

Tags: java, networking, permissions, localhost, rmi

I am trying to run my server named SampleServer. I am using windows and this is what i did:

in cmd:

```
javaw rmiregistry 1099
cd C:\Users\Home\workspace\RMI\src
java -Djava.security.policy=policy SampleServer 1099
```

i get the following error:

```
binding //localhost:1099/Sample
New instance of Sample created
Sample server failed:Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is:

        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I've tried using a different port # such as 4719 for rmiregistry but i receive the same error. I made sure that my firewall was disabled but the problem persist. I made sure that the port is not already being used. I really hope someone can help me.

Picture of my desktop with folders of project, eclipse window and cmd open:
http://s22.postimg.org/uq00qzslr/picyture.png

Code:

SampleServer:

```
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class SampleServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("usage: java SampleServer rmi_port");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        // Create and install a security manager
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        try {
            // first command-line argument is the port of the rmiregistry
            int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            String url = "//localhost:" + port + "/Sample";
            System.out.println("binding " + url);
            Naming.rebind(url, new Sample());
            // Naming.rebind("Sample", new Sample());
            System.out.println("server " + url + " is running...");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Sample server failed:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

SampleClient:

```
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public class SampleClient  {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            if (args.length < 3) {
                System.err.println("usage: java SampleClient host port string... \n");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            String url = "//" + args[0] + ":" + port + "/Sample";
            System.out.println("looking up " + url);

            SampleInterface sample = (SampleInterface)Naming.lookup(url);

            // args[2] onward are the strings we want to reverse
            for (int i=2; i < args.length; ++i)
                // call the remote method and print the return
                System.out.println(sample.invert(args[i]));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("SampleClient exception: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

SampleInterface:

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface SampleInterface extends Remote {
    public String invert(String msg) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Sample:

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.*;

// this is the class with remote methods

public class Sample
  extends UnicastRemoteObject
  implements SampleInterface {

    private int a;

    public Sample() throws RemoteException {
    System.out.println("New instance of Sample created");
    a = 1;
    }

    public String invert(String m) throws RemoteException {
        // return input message with characters reversed
        System.out.println("invert("+m+") a=" + a);
        return new StringBuffer(m).reverse().toString();
    }
}
```

policy:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> javaw rmiregistry 1099

Stop right there. This is already wrong. 'rmiregistry' is an executable, not the name of a Java class you can execute with 'java' or 'javaw'. Just use 'rmiregistry'.

Comment: but then i get:try is not recognized as an internal or external command. I thought the command to start was start rmiregistry or if that didn't work which it doesn't in my case, javaw rmiregistry). Is there a specific download that i need to make this work or a specific dir to be in?

Comment: 'try' *isn't* an internal or external command. Remove it. There's nothing here that says to use that. The command you want is 'rmiregistry'. Clearly you weren't executing what you think you're executing.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when there is no service running on the port, you are trying to connect. As said by EJP, `rmiregistry` is a tool which can be started by `rmiregistry &` in the background (JDK 7). I would recommend you that you check your firewall or connectivity issue with the port.

Comment: As he hasn't actually started the Registry correctly, it isn't necessary to postulate any additional failure mechanisms.

Comment: You won't help anybody out by raising irrelevant matter.